# TIBCO file transfer - run script on source or target server?

Tags: file-transfer, execute, tibco

We're looking at using TIBCO initially to schedule file transfers between Linux servers but we have an additional question on pre-/post-processing data.

Can TIBCO be configured to run a Shell script (or any other Perl, Python, etc script) on the source Server before transferring a file OR run a script on the target Server after receiving a file?

Answer (score 0):

You might need to be more specific with which particular TIBCO product you are referring to as they have a suite of products that run different scripts/languages.

For example TIBCO BusinessWorks can run java code. You just need activate java nature (6.X) or use the java palette (5.X)